# Handling no text in textField (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uibutton

I have a basic chat application and I want it so that when inputTextField.text == nil nothing no information gets sent from the textField. The solution I attempted was to disable the button if inputTextField.text == nil but that proved futile. Below is the both the instantiation of the button and the function that handles the send.
I have included a screen shot of the build that shows what it looks like when inputTextField.text == nil.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7yOC.png)

I do not want the chat bubbles to show.

Any suggestions?

```
lazy var sendButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Send", for: UIControlState())
    let titleColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 137/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1)
    button.setTitleColor(titleColor, for: UIControlState())
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

func handleSend(){
    print(inputTextField)

    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.managedObjectContext

    if inputTextField.text == nil {
        sendButton.isEnabled = false
    }else{
        FriendsController.createMessageWithText(inputTextField.text!, friend: friend!, minutesAgo: 0, context: context, isSender: true)
    }

    do{

        try context.save()
        inputTextField.text = nil

    }catch let err {
        print(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: How about testing whether the text is `""`?

Comment: if(inputTextField.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty){ //empty }

Comment: Isn't it the matter of unwrapping an optional value correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the textfield is empty on your handleSend() function. This will trim the extra spaces before and after the input string as well

```
let inputString = inputTextField.text
if(inputString.trimmingCharacters
   (in:CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? "").isEmpty {
     print("String is nil or empty")
}else {
    //do your code for sending the data
}
```

Comment: `if inputTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty == true {`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a big deal according to me.You can just check if inputTextField.text == "".And whenever there will be no text then your requirement will be fullfilled.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using sent event `Editing Changed` of `UITextField`.

```
@IBAction func textFieldDidChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
     if sender.text == "" {
         sendButton.isEnabled = false
     } else {
         sendButton.isEnabled = true
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `sendButton.isEnabled = sender.text != ""`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes . Thats right. Thanks for pointing it out. But it isn't it `sendButton.isEnabled = !(sender.text == "")`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no text in the input text field it doesn't mean that is nil , is just blank, you can check for the textfield.text.characters.count and see that is bigger than 0

Answer (score 0):

Please set UITextField Delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange and you can handle when no text then disable and enable

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    if textField.text?.characters.count == 0{
        sendButton.isEnabled = false
    }else{
        sendButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    return true
}
```

I hope it's working for you!.